# Combine Duplicate keys in dictionary and add its values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which is defined as following:

```
movies=[('x',57),('y', 23),('z', 12), ('y', 10), ('x',22),('y',12)]
```

It can be seen that there are duplicate values in the dictionary. Hence I combined them and the resultant dicionsry looks as shown:

```
{'x': [57, 22], 'y': [23,10,12], 'z': [12]}
```

Whenever there are two or more values represented by the key I want the final value of the final key of the final dictionary to be the average of the key values in the original dictionary.It is important to note that the average should take place whenver there are two or more values associated with a single key.

Hence the final dictionary should be as follows:

```
{'x': [39.5], 'y': [15], 'z': [12]}
```

Where:

1. key x=57+22/2=39.5
2. key y=23+10+12/3=15
3. Key z=12 (do note that in this case the value remains same as there is a single occourence of key z)

Comment: Can you post the code for combining the duplicate values ?

Comment: z=12 isn't a special case. The average of `[12]` is `12`. What have you tried…? Just loop over the dict and average those lists…!?

Comment: `{k: sum(v) / len(v) for k, v in combined_dict.items()}`…

Comment: Your variable *movies* does not refer to a dictionary. It's a list of 2-tuples

Comment: 57 + 22/2 = 39.5? You mean (57 + 22)/2? Day ruined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not functionally different to other answers but this has no reliance on additional module imports:

```
movies = [('x', 57), ('y', 23), ('z', 12), ('y', 10), ('x', 22), ('y', 12)]

md = dict()

for k, v in movies:
    md.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

md = {k: [sum(v) / len(v)] for k, v in md.items()}

print(md)
```

**Output:**

```
{'x': [39.5], 'y': [15.0], 'z': [12.0]}
```

Output is as required in the OP's question but surely keeping the mean in a list is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

traverse through the data, save the character as key and values in a list.

then again traverse to calculate the avg of the values

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict as dd
>>> movies=[('x',57),('y', 23),('z', 12), ('y', 10), ('x',22),('y',12)]
>>> x = dd(list)
>>> 
>>> for a, v in movies:
...     x[a].append(v)
... 
>>> for i, v in x.items():
...     x[i]=[sum(v)/len(v)]
... 
>>> x
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'x': [39.5], 'y': [15.0], 'z': [12.0]})
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

i do this, it's works (but maybe there is a better way)

```
my_dic = {'x': [57, 22], 'y': [23,10,12], 'z': [12]}
for key in my_dic:
    if len(my_dic[key]) > 1:
        my_dic[key] = [sum(my_dic[key]) / len(my_dic[key])]
    
print(my_dic)
```

Comment: Omit the `if..else` and always do `sum / len`, it'll give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` for that

```py
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean

{key:[mean(item[1] for item in group)] 
for key ,group in groupby(
  sorted(movies, key=lambda x: x[0]), 
  lambda x: x[0]
)}
```

Output:

```
{'x': [39.5], 'y': [15], 'z': [12]}
```

Comment: The list would need to be sorted by "key" for that to work correctly…

Comment: I first tried with sorted, but then noticed that the correct answer is still obtained without this step.

Comment: Please provide a complete, working example. It's not clear what `data` refers to in your code, and it doesn't work with either of OP's variables.

Comment: my bad, you are right:) I've updated the solution

Comment: OK. Note that it's questionable whether sorting first still gives "better performance"…